# 2016 Macbook keyboard key barely working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a new Macbook 2016 and the space bar has been acting up. If I smash it down hard enough I can get the space character to appear but that's not very practical.

I read the Macbook marketing page (https://www.apple.com/macbook/design/) to confirm that they did change the design (since the keys feel noticeably different from years past). It seems to have had to opposite consequence from their intention in that the edge of my spacebar (right where my right thumb sits) doesn't really work but the middle is fine.

I tried to blow into the keyboard and I also turned the laptop upside down and pressed the keys to maybe get rid of any crumbs.

Are there any solutions to this? Should I risk taking the space bar off and checking out their new 'butterfly' design to see if I can fix it?

Comment: Apple is now working through a class-action lawsuit over the defective design of their butterfly keyboards. See: [Class-action lawsuit claims Apple's 'butterfly' keyboard is defective](https://www.techspot.com/news/74612-class-action-lawsuit-claims-apple-butterfly-keyboard-defective.html)

Comment: There is also a change.org petition relative to the 2016 mbp’s keyboard.

Comment: Link - https://www.change.org/p/apple-apple-recall-macbook-pro-w-defective-keyboard-replace-with-different-working-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

That is obviously a hardware issue on *your* specific device (maybe some other devices of the same series are concerned).

The best thing to do is to contact the Apple assistance (online or *via* a physical Apple Store) and see what they can do.

If you take the space bar off, you'll probably lose your warranty.